# acumulador dentro de bucle for para in if anidado

Tags: java

Llego a un parte en la cual necesito acumular el valor del interés por cada paso del for teniendo en cuenta el if anidado.

El problema es que no reconoce la variable interés creada dentro del if.

```
package reto1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reto1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("N: ");
        int Numerocuenta = input.nextInt();
        int total_interes = 0;  
        for (int i=0;i<Numerocuenta;i++){
            
            System.out.println("Numero de cuenta: ");
            long numero_cuenta = input.nextLong();
  
            //String fecha;
            //if (fecha.length()=10){
            
            System.out.println("Fecha de apertura: ");
            String fecha = input.next();

            System.out.println("Tipo de cuenta: ");
            int tipo_cuenta = input.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("Saldo de la cuenta: ");
            double saldo_cuenta = input.nextDouble();
               
            if (tipo_cuenta==1){
                double interes = 0.015*saldo_cuenta;
                double valor_total_intereses = saldo_cuenta*0.015+saldo_cuenta;
                System.out.println("interes: " + valor_total_intereses);
                
            }if (tipo_cuenta==2){    
                double interes = 0.017*saldo_cuenta;
                double valor_total_intereses = saldo_cuenta*0.015+saldo_cuenta;
                System.out.println("interes: " + valor_total_intereses);
                
            }if (tipo_cuenta==3){
                double interes = 0.016*saldo_cuenta;
                double valor_total_intereses = saldo_cuenta*0.015+saldo_cuenta;
                System.out.println("interes: " + valor_total_intereses);}
                
            total_interes += interes;   
            System.out.println("total intereses: " + total_interes);
                
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las variables locales son accesibles desde su declaración hasta el final del bloque de código del fichero en el que han sido declaradas.
Un bloque de código viene determinado por una pareja de llaves { }.
Si el bloque donde se ha declarado la variable local contiene a su vez otros bloques, también es accesible dentro de ellos.
En caso de que una variable aparezca declarada en varios niveles de anidamiento dentro de un bloque, prevalece la declaración del bloque más interno.

```
    if (tipo_cuenta==2){    
         double interes = 0.017*saldo_cuenta;//variable local
         double valor_total_intereses = saldo_cuenta*0.015+saldo_cuenta;//variable local
                System.out.println("interes: " + valor_total_intereses);
                
            }
```

las variables globales son declarados fuera de las funciones teniendo ámbito global, es decir, pueden ser accedidas desde cualquier parte del programa.

```
    double total_interes = 0; 
    double interes=0; 
    for (int i=0;i<numeroCuenta;i++){
        
        System.out.println("Numero de cuenta: ");
        long numero_cuenta = input.nextLong();
        
        System.out.println("Fecha de apertura: ");
        String fecha = input.next();

        System.out.println("Tipo de cuenta: ");
        int tipo_cuenta = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Saldo de la cuenta: ");
        double saldo_cuenta = input.nextDouble();
           
        if (tipo_cuenta==1){
            interes = 0.015*saldo_cuenta;//variable global
            double valor_total_intereses = saldo_cuenta*0.015+saldo_cuenta;
            System.out.println("interes: " + valor_total_intereses);
            
        }if (tipo_cuenta==2){    
            interes = 0.017*saldo_cuenta;
            double valor_total_intereses = saldo_cuenta*0.015+saldo_cuenta;
            System.out.println("interes: " + valor_total_intereses);
            
        }if (tipo_cuenta==3){
            interes = 0.016*saldo_cuenta;
            double valor_total_intereses = saldo_cuenta*0.015+saldo_cuenta;
            System.out.println("interes: " + valor_total_intereses);
        }
            
        total_interes += interes;   
        System.out.println("total intereses: " + total_interes);
            
        }
```